# Finding functions using specific macro

Tags: module, macros, attributes, elixir, metaprogramming

Is there a way I can find all the functions listed using a specific macro I've created?  I was thinking it would be possible to find them using the `:application.get_key` function.

Something Like

```
defmodule DefFooModule do
  defmacro deffoo(head, body) do
    quote do
      def unquote(head) do
        unquote(body[:do])
      end
    end
  end

  def find_all_foos do
    {:ok, modules} = :application.get_key(:app, :modules)
    ## something here???
    ## output [
    ##  AnotherModule.do_something/0, 
    ##  AnotherModule.do_something_else/0, 
    ##  AnotherModule2.do_something_2/0
    ## ]
  end
end

defmodule AnotherModule do
  deffoo do_something do
    ## function goes in here
  end
  deffoo do_something_else do
    ## function goes in here
  end
end
defmodule AnotherModule2 do
  deffoo do_something_2 do
    ## function goes in here
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mix xref` task to list the callers of a module, but not of a specific macro/function. If you have only this macro defined in a module you can try with `mix xref callers MyModule`.

I can suggest a custom solution that will work only for tracking macro calls. You need to be running OTP 21.2 or higher in order to have [:persistent_term](https://erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html) available. If you are using an older OTP version, the `:persistent_term` can be replaced by an ETS, but the logic is the same.

```
defmodule T do
  defmacro foo() do
    callers = :persistent_term.get(:macro_callers, [])

    file_line = __CALLER__.file <> ":#{__CALLER__.line}"
    caller_info = {file_line, __CALLER__.module, __CALLER__.function}

    :persistent_term.put(:macro_callers, [ caller_info | callers])

    quote do
      1 + 2
    end
  end

  def get_callers(), do: :persistent_term.get(:macro_callers, [])
end

defmodule T2 do
  require T
  def bar(), do: T.foo()
end


defmodule T3 do
  require T
  def baz(), do: T.foo()
end

defmodule T4 do
  require T
  def boo(), do: T.foo()
end
```

If you add some code outside the `quote` block of a macro, it will be executed once when the macro is processed during compilation. It has access to the `__CALLER__` macro that returns the current calling environment. The result of calling `__CALLER__` is a [Macro.Env](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Macro.Env.html) struct. In this specific example, this code stores the file, line, module, function name and function arity of the caller in the [:persistent_term](https://erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html) so you can later retrieve it.

Executing `T.get_callers` at runtime after compiling all the modules are compiled returns the following result:

```
[
  {"/Users/ivan/macro_callers.ex:31", T4, {:boo, 0}},
  {"/Users/ivan/macro_callers.ex:26", T3, {:baz, 0}},
  {"/Users/ivan/macro_callers.ex:20", T2, {:bar, 0}}
]
```